# How can I grep for a block of text that contains certain words across several lines? And how can I do that piped from tail -f?

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

I want to tail a log file and print ONLY blocks of text that match the regex pattern `.*\n.*\nABC(.*\n){1-6}XYZ`.  In case my regex is wrong already, I want to match this example:

```
TIMESTAMP HERE
LOG ENTRY HEADER
ABC
STUFF
...
STUFF
XYZ
```

Or what I'd *really* like is to match the above only when the string "ZZZ" doesn't appear anywhere in the match.

My workaround solution is to do the following:

```
tail -f file | egrep --line-buffered -B 2 -A 6
```

But obviously this returns much more than I'd like.  I also don't have the option to install packages, but I do have `awk` and `sed` available.

Answer (score 1):

You could select any block from "TIMESTAMP" to "XYZ" and introduce NUL as separator after the block via `sed`, then sieve out via other tools, e.g. `grep` and remove the NUL byte in the end:

```
tail -f file |
  sed -n '/TIMESTAMP/,/XYZ/{/XYZ/s/$/\x00/;p}' |
  grep -z 'ABC' |
  grep -z -v 'ZZZ' |
  tr -d '\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is determine the starting and ending pattern. For example, let's use `TIMESTAMP HERE` and `XYZ` for that purpose and use sed to find all the lines in betweeen.

`sed -n '/^TIMESTAMP HERE/,/^XYZ/p' logfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**:

```
tail -f log | sed '/\n/!N;N;/\nABC$/!D;N;N;N;N;N;N;/ZZZ/d'
```

Displays a line that matches the `ABC` template, 2 preceding and 6 following if they do not have a template `ZZZ`

There are always 3 lines in the buffer. We check the last one. If there are no matches, delete the first one and move the execution to the beginning of the script. If there is a match, add 6 more lines. The decision to print is taken from the match according to the `ZZZ` pattern.

**Mismatch**:
Suppose the `XYZ` pattern must match the end of the record block. Then:

```
tail -f | sed ':1;N;/XYZ/!b1;/ZZZ/d'
```

I don't see the need for unbuffered output here, but `-u` flag provides this capability in the `sed` streaming editor.

It is also possible to enter a pattern for the beginning of a recording block:

```
tail -f | sed '/TIMESTAMP/!d;:1;N;/XYZ/!b1;/ZZZ/d'
```

The above scripts add to the SED editor buffer(pattern space) all lines from the beginning of the recording to the end and a match is made with the `ZZZ` template, which results in the determination of deleting the entire record or printing.

Another option, if the log blocks contain the same number of lines, then they can be counted and displayed exactly as much as necessary as in your attempt with egrep.
Let us choose the plus + symbol as the counter. In this example, we will count up to five, but you can change it in this template - `+\{5\}`:

```
tail -f log | sed ':1;x;s/$/+/;/+\{5\}/!{x;N;b1};s/.*//;x'
```

You can also add the beginning of the account and delete by template:

```
tail -f log | sed '/TIMESTAMP/!d;:1;x;s/$/+/;/+\{5\}/!{x;N;b1};s/.*//;x;/ZZZ/d'
```

The counter works like this. The SED editor has two buffers - pattern space and hold space. The string is written to the pattern space. The `x` command changes the contents of both buffers and we write a plus sign at the end of hold space and check their number if the pattern matches 5 plus we print the contents, otherwise we add the next line and increase the counter. After 5 lines match, we reset the counter and the process repeats.

Comment: Change `/\nABC$/` to `/ABC[^\n]*$/` for a part of a string.